# Get the index value each for loop

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, loops, for-loop

I have the for loop like as follow:

```
for(NSMutableDictionary *dict in arr_thisWeek){

     NSLog("%d",[arr_thisWeek objectATIndex:?????);
  }
```

How to get the index value??

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSInteger index = 0;

for(NSMutableDictionary *dict in arr_thisWeek){
    NSLog("%d",[arr_thisWeek objectATIndex:index);

    index++;
}
```

But you already have the item at that index so you shouldn't need it for array iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arr_thisWeek=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"value1",@"value2",@"value3",@"value4", nil];
[arr_thisWeek enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
               NSLog(@"index: %d  , Value: %@",idx,obj);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the index :

```
for(NSMutableDictionary *dict in arr_thisWeek){
    NSLog("%d",[arr_thisWeek indexOfObject:dict);
}
```

Comment: not correct.. & getting the warning

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer:

```
[arr_thisWeek enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"Index %i holds object: %@", idx, obj);
}];
```

A few notes on this block enumeration syntax:

- You don't need to remember how to write it. Just type `[arr_thisWeek enum...` and you'll find it in the autocompletion box (assuming Xcode IDE or similar).
- If you know, for instance, that the objects are `NSMutableDictionaries` and you want access to their methods, change `id obj` to `NSMutableDictionary* obj`.
- I recommend changing the variable name `obj` to something clearer.
- Most importantly: the iterated code is *not* a loop - it is a **block** that is executed several times. This means:

  - If you want to **continue** (i.e. exit the current iteration and continue to the next), you need to do: `return;`. This exits the block, while further calls to the block (further iterations) will continue as normal.
  - If you want to **break** (i.e. stop the loop immediately), you need to do: `*stop = YES;`. This causes no further blocks to be executed. Note that this does not exit the *current* block. So to get normal 'return behavior', do: `*stop = YES; return;`.